# Schwinn 1979 12 speed

Tags: identify-this-bike

I purchased a vintage Schwinn 12 speed recently, the bike had been re-painted and I cannot figure out the model?

Here is what I know the head badge says 3219 meaning the bike was mfg on the 321 first day of 1979 or Nov.17th 1979 this is confirmed by the mfg stamp on the rear lower wheel mount of the right side of the frame G1179, if I understand correctly the "G" means the bike was produced by Giant Bicycles in Taiwan, and the 1179 confirms the November of 79 manufactures date. On the left hub mount there is a serial number of 318514?

Everything I find on serial numbers says that there should be a LQ in front of the number, LQ meaning again the letter codes used for a Nov. of 79 mfg period? There is not? When looking up the number I get no results unless I use the LQ prefix?

LQ318514 comes up that the bike is a Chicago made Bicycle, yet the date stamp says Giant? Is there any way to cross reference the serial number and find out the Model of the bike? I believe that it is a Approved World Sport, except the Schwinn catalogs do not show the World Sport as a 12 speed?

Comment: Adding some photos might help. Maybe a side view? '79 is pre-indexing isn't it? Could be that someone changed the rear wheel.

Comment: you know what the 1st thing a thief does with a clipped bike? maybe attempt to verify you are not, what we call in the US- unintentionally RSP? classic schwinns are popular amoung the secondary bike mkt. use caution.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're right on the age based on this document, 
http://thirtythree.org/projects-unconverted/Lowrider%20Bicycle%20Restoration/Identifying%20Schwinn%20Frames.pdf

G from Taiwan, in 1979.   As the document mentions, even though the date code is 79 it could have been used in 1980's line up.

The 1980 catalog shows a couple 12 speed's 
http://schwinncruisers.com/catalogs/1980.html

Only the Voyageur 11.8 says it's Schwinn-Approved making it made most likely from Taiwan.
Without any pictures or remaining decals this may be the most likely model.